# How is the "Execute a Command" feature of Remmina used correctly?

Tags: rdp, remmina

I am using Remmina on Pop!_OS 21.10 to remotely connect to a Windows 10 machine via RDP. This is working well, however, I am having some difficulty understanding how exactly the "Execute a Command" feature found in Connection Profile > Behavior works.

[image: Remmina connection settings]

I couldn't find anything related to this in the user guide or much discussion around this anywhere. I would like to execute a command after connecting, but the command does not execute. The command I would like to run will remove the GNOME titlebar: `xprop -name "Windows 10 RDP" -format _MOTIF_WM_HINTS 32c -set _MOTIF_WM_HINTS 2`. This works as expected when executed directly in the terminal, but not when set identically in the "After connecting" field shown above.

My troubleshooting steps thus far:

- Wrap the command in a script, and call the script from the Remmina config. Command still did not execute.
- Remmina was originally installed as Flatpak, and I thought maybe there was an issue executing a command outside of its sandbox. Uninstalling and re-installed from .deb package did not resolve the issue.
- Test "Before Connecting" command; this also did not execute.
- Create new connection profiles from scratch.
- Test with connection to different machines (Windows & Linux)

Comment: The only feedback I received since I want to use the before part to set-up a double SSH tunnel/jump is when I had my quotes wrong, it crashed the client with that in the message log.  Besides that, I am watching for a new expected setsid process that never appears but works and appears when manually executing the fish function I made to accomplish all of this, and of course my connection never succeeds only using the Remmina client..  I don't see much for it in the debugging message log view either, except barely a log for `(remmina_exec_command) - Initiating connection`.